# tab bar did select delegate methods give the previously selected tab index in ios, swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I'm trying to detect which tab selected by the user, realtime. as an example, if user selecte `0 th` index, at the same time I want to get that user has selected the `zeroth` index tab. so for that , I used `tabbarcontroller` delegate method like below.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        print("the selected index is : \(selectedIndex)")
    }
```

but this shows the previous view controller.as an example think I'm in `second tab` and then I select the `first tab` then this prints the index as `2`.so how can I get the correct selected tab.
hope your help with this.

Comment: checkout my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get index of selected `UITabBarItem` by getting position of that particular item from array of items in `UITabBar`. Try this out

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("the selected index is : \(tabBar.items.index(of: item))")
}
```

Comment: thanx and nice.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.1**:

```
 override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
     guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
     print("the selected index is : \(String(describing: items.index(of: item)))")
}
```